# JQuery Highlight plugin, argument somehow undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm modifying the [jQuery highlight plugin](http://bartaz.github.io/sandbox.js/jquery.highlight.html). I want to provide a `title` argument in addition to `element: 'abbr'`.

Here's a snippet with the plugin:

```js
jQuery.extend({
  highlight: function (node, re, nodeName, className, titleVal) {
    if (node.nodeType === 3) {
      var match = node.data.match(re);
      if (match) {
        console.log('Title after: ' + titleVal);
        var highlight = document.createElement(nodeName || 'span');
        highlight.className = className || 'highlight';
        highlight.setAttribute('title', titleVal);
        var wordNode = node.splitText(match.index);
        wordNode.splitText(match[0].length);
        var wordClone = wordNode.cloneNode(true);
        highlight.appendChild(wordClone);
        wordNode.parentNode.replaceChild(highlight, wordNode);
        return 1; //skip added node in parent
      }
    } else if ((node.nodeType === 1 && node.childNodes) && // only element nodes that have children
        !/(script|style)/i.test(node.tagName) && // ignore script and style nodes
        !(node.tagName === nodeName.toUpperCase() && node.className === className)) { // skip if already highlighted
      for (var i = 0; i < node.childNodes.length; i++) {
        i += jQuery.highlight(node.childNodes[i], re, nodeName, className);
      }
    }
    return 0;
  }
});

jQuery.fn.unhighlight = function (options) {
  var settings = { className: 'highlight', element: 'span' };
  jQuery.extend(settings, options);

  return this.find(settings.element + "." + settings.className).each(function () {
    var parent = this.parentNode;
    parent.replaceChild(this.firstChild, this);
    parent.normalize();
  }).end();
};

jQuery.fn.highlight = function (words, options) {
  var settings = { className: 'highlight', element: 'span', titleVal: 'Default', caseSensitive: false, wordsOnly: false };
  jQuery.extend(settings, options);
  console.log('Title passed:' + settings.titleVal);
  if (words.constructor === String) {
    words = [words];
  }
  words = jQuery.grep(words, function(word, i){
    return word != '';
  });
  words = jQuery.map(words, function(word, i) {
    return word.replace(/[-[\]{}()*+?.,\\^$|#\s]/g, "\\$&");
  });
  if (words.length == 0) { return this; };

  var flag = settings.caseSensitive ? "" : "i";
  var pattern = "(" + words.join("|") + ")";
  if (settings.wordsOnly) {
    pattern = "\\b" + pattern + "\\b";
  }
  var re = new RegExp(pattern, flag);
  
  return this.each(function () {
    console.log('Title before: ' + settings.titleVal);
    jQuery.highlight(this, re, settings.element, settings.className, settings.titleVal);
  });
};
```

```css
abbr { text-decoration: underline; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>These are a collection of words for an example. Kthx.</p>
<button onclick="$('p').highlight('collection', {element: 'abbr', titleVal: 'A group of things or people'})">What's "collection"?</button>
```

Look at the console. Notice that the title is successfully passed, is defined right before calling the plugin function, then is undefined inside it. I'm pretty sure it's something simple, but I'm not seeing it.

Comment: In the `jQuery.extend` part there’s a line with `i += jQuery.highlight(node.childNodes[i], re, nodeName, className);` inside the `for` loop. Adding a `, titleVal` to the argument list of that function call seems to fix it. I’m not sure whether other bugs might occur when including that argument, though.

Comment: That's totally it, thank you! Feel free to post that answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing that line in the `for` loop

```
i += jQuery.highlight(node.childNodes[i], re, nodeName, className);
```

to

```
i += jQuery.highlight(node.childNodes[i], re, nodeName, className, titleVal);
```

fixes it.